# Fragment reloading again when switching back to it

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have bottom navigation view implemented in my activity it has two fragment **Home fragment** and **Account fragment**. In my Home fragment I am loading products list and when I go to Account fragment and switch back to Home fragment again then data do not persists its load again.

Below is my code:

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

ProductAdapter adapter;
List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
ProgressBar progress;
RecyclerView productRecycler;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    progress = view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    productRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.productRecycler);
    productRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    productRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    loadProducts();

       android.app.Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.homeFragment2);
  
        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = (getActivity()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
        fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
        fragTransaction.commit();

    return view;
}

private void loadProducts(){

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    ApiService apiService  = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    Call<List<Product>> call = apiService.getProducts();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Product>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Product>> call, Response<List<Product>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                productList = response.body();
                adapter = new ProductAdapter(productList,getActivity());
                productRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Product>> call, Throwable t) {
           progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           TastyToast.makeText(getActivity(),t.getMessage(),TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,TastyToast.ERROR).show();
         }
     });
   }
}
```

How can I achieve desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your oncreate function. So when you go back oncreate call and refresh the fragment

```
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

And in onBackPress()

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: How to get fragment tag.

Comment: Your_Fragment_TAG is the name you gave your fragment when you created it

This code is for support library.

If you're not supporting older devices, just use getFragmentManager instead of getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: and where to add `onBackPressed()` in fragment or in activity

Comment: I am using navigation component with bottom nav view

Comment: in your current fragment

Comment: If you not using TAG then try this

**Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
if (currentFragment instanceof "NAME OF YOUR FRAGMENT CLASS") {
 FragmentTransaction fragTransaction =   (getActivity()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
 fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
 fragTransaction.commit();}**
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227572/discussion-between-user8833355-and-digvijay).

Comment: Digvijay for Navigation component you can use:

OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
       @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
      }
 };

Answer (score 0):

you can consider using a ViewModel design.

If however, you want to just make minimal changes to your code, you can

1. turn on setRetainInstance(true)
2. create Adapter in onCreate(), not inside loadProducts().
3. call rv.setAdapter in onCreateView, not inside loadProducts().
4. create a method to populate the list in your adapter instead of re-creating it everytime when you call loadProducts().
5. move loadProducts() from onCreateView() to onCreate().

your current code will cause loadProducts to be called everytime you rotate your device.

Comment: There is no change of loading products in onCreate().Its still loading  again.